# Django Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: scraping_vacancy.title - how can I fix?

Tags: python, django

Problem! My script worked once and then produces such an error

```
IntegrityError at /index/
UNIQUE constraint failed: scraping_vacancy.title
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: scraping_vacancy.title
Exception Location: /Users/dmitrigornakov/Documents/Django/parser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 396
Python Executable:  /Users/dmitrigornakov/Documents/Django/parser/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.2
```

code source: https://github.com/visualGravitySense/parser

Code in views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from scraping.utils import *
from scraping.models import *

def home(request):

    jobs = djinni()
    city = City.objects.get(name='Kyiv')
    speciality = Speciality.objects.get(name='Python')
    v = Vacancy.objects.filter(city=city, speciality=speciality).values('url')
    url_list = [i['url'] for i in v]
    for job in jobs:
        if job['href'] not in url_list:
            vacancy = Vacancy(city=city, speciality=speciality, url=job['href'], title=job['title'], description=job['descript'], company=job['company'])
            vacancy.save()

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'jobs': jobs})
```

Comment: Well it means that you are constructing a `Vacancy` with a title that already exists. But the `title` field in the `Vacancy` model is marked unique, so the database rejects creating a new entry.

Comment: So to solve the problem, if you dont have any unique field, you can just set an id column to auto-increment and set it as the primary key, and remove the unique constraint from your `title` field for the `Vacancy` model

Answer (score 0):

If unique contraint for title is not needed remove it in models.py in **scraping** folder:

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True,  verbose_name='Адрес вакансии')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,  verbose_name='Заголовок вакансии')
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание вакансии')
   company = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, verbose_name='Название компании')
   city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name='Город', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, verbose_name='Специальность', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

after this change, dont forget to do `python manage.py makemigrations`

And after `python manage.py migrate scraping 00XX` (where 00XX is number of migration provided by make migrations)